# A system of equations Olympiad question

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, contest-math

Find all non-zero real numbers $x,y,z$ which satisfy the system of equations:
\begin{align}
(x^2+xy+y^2)(y^2+yz+z^2)(z^2+zx+x^2)&=xyz,\\(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)(y^4+y^2z^2+z^4)(z^4+z^2x^2+x^4)&=x^3y^3z^3
\end{align}
It's an indian olympiad question. Can you guys help me out in solving it please ?

edit:

I have tried to write the first equation as:
*$(\frac{x^3-y^3}{x-y})(\frac{y^3-z^3}{y-z})(\frac{z^3-x^3}{z-x})$ = xyz*

And second equation as:
*$(\frac{x^6-y^6}{x^2-y^2})(\frac{y^6-z^6}{y^2-z^2})(\frac{z^6-x^6}{z^2-x^2}) = x^3y^3z^3$*

Then divided the two to get:
*$(\frac{x^3+y^3}{x+y})(\frac{y^3+z^3}{y+z})(\frac{z^3+x^3}{z+x}) = x^2y^2z^2$*

After that I have no sign what to do??

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I appreciate you adding your attempt so far to the question text. However, in general, you can't go from your first equation to your second one. I'll leave that to somebody else to possibly explain that to you as I'm going to bed now.  Note, however, that I have retracted my down vote and my close vote (and even gave an up vote) as I don't believe they're appropriate now.

Comment: Regarding your second equation, in my comment above, I thought you did something different than what you did. However, now that I look at it again, I see you have the LHS matching what you wrote earlier, but the RHS has $xyz$ cubed while the original question text has it squared. Which one is correct?

Comment: I have corrected it

Comment: The only answer is $x = y = z = \frac13$. Hint: $|u + u^{-1} - 1| \ge 1$ for all real $u \ne 0$ and $= 1$ when and only when $u = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obtained $$\left(\frac{x^3+y^3}{x+y}\right)\!\!\left(\frac{y^3+z^3}{y+z}\right)\!\!\left(\frac{z^3+x^3}{z+x}\right) = x^2y^2z^2$$
which is equivalent to
$$\prod_\mathrm{cyc}(x^2-xy+y^2)=x^2y^2z^2.$$
Dividing throughout by $xy\cdot yz\cdot zx$, we get
$$\prod_{\mathrm{cyc}}\left(\frac{x}{y}-1+\frac{y}{x}\right)=1.$$
Now, we use the hint given by achille hui in the comments. For every nonzero $u\in\mathbb R$, we have $|u+u^{-1}-1|\geq 1$ with equality exactly when $u=1$. To see this, note that if $u>0$, then $u+u^{-1}\geq2$ by AM-GM inequality, whereas if $u<0$ then by the same logic, $u+u^{-1}\leq -2$. Now, it follows from the multiplicity of $|\cdot|$ that
$$\prod_{\mathrm{cyc}}\left|\frac{x}{y}-1+\frac{y}{x}\right|=1.$$
If any one of the terms in the cyclic product is $>1$, then that forces one of the other terms to be $<1$, which we know to be impossible. This implies that all the terms are exactly one, so that $x/y=1$ and $x=y$. Similarly $y=z$, so $x=y=z$. The rest is easy.

Comment: +1 yup, the rest is easy ;-p